# Filtering nested JSON in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filter, aws-glue

We would like to use an AWS-Glue Job to filter JSON messages within an s3 bucket.

Here is some example JSON:

```
{ "property": {"subproperty1": "A", "subproperty2": "B" }}
{ "property": {"subproperty1": "C", "subproperty2": "D" }}
```

We want to filter on `subproperty1 in ["A", "B"]`. This is what we try:

```
applyFilter1 = Filter.apply(
  frame = datasource0, 
  f = lambda x: x["property.subproperty1"] in ["A", "B"]
)
```

Output is then written so a new s3 bucket as follows:

```
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = applyFilter1, 
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {"path": "s3://<my-s3-location>"}, 
    format = "json", 
    transformation_ctx = "datasink2"
)
```

Unfortunately the resulting file is empty. Any idea? Is filtering nested expressions like this supported in AWS Glue?

Comment: Turns out that changing the filter property to this: `f = lambda x: x["property"]["subproperty1"] in ["A", "B"]` solves the issue.