# Unnesting multiple nested arrays into separate rows with AWS Glue ETL

Tags: python, arrays, etl, aws-glue

I am attempting to unnest JSON arrays of arrays in AWS Glue with Python

Example data structure is as follows:

```
{
    "country": "US",
    "states": [
        {
            "stateId": -8727116505311523857,
            "events": [
                {
                    "eventId": 9087712927864446976,
                    "name": "exampleName1",
                    "time": 1.515376892153E9,
                    "value": 0.0,
                    "parameters": {
                        "exampleparam1": "27"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "eventId": 7885892179028651008,
                    "name": "exampleName2",
                    "time": 1.515376892154E9,
                    "value": 0.0,
                    "parameters": {
                        "exampleparam1": "0",
                        "exampleparam2": "18",
                        "exampleparam3": "21303",
                        "exampleparam4": "27",
                        "exampleparam5": "2",
                        "exampleparam6": "2",
                        "exampleparam7": "3",
                        "exampleparam8": "18",
                        "exampleparam9": "1",
                        "exampleparam10": "12"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "duration": 1853.938
}
```

My ideal outcome is to split each line of json into multiple rows, each of which contains all the top level data, but only one event out of the events array.

Due to the multiple levels of nesting it seems that `unnest()` will not have the desired effect.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/).  I hope you are looking something like this to flatten the json file and process  Also, please take a look at this, [example for filtering data from nested JSONs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687238/filtering-nested-json-in-aws-glue)

Comment: I ended up solving this by using `explode()`, then splitting the states column into separate stateID and events nested array columns. Then finally exploding the events array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EricKeen Can you share you code, I have similar requirement, and your code using explode will be of great help

Comment: Apologies we've since moved to GCP and this was a lot easier to handle. I don't have the legacy code to hand.